# Automating USB Connection/Disconnection for HID device on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero, hid

I have a blood pressure monitor device that requires manual USB connection and disconnection each time I want to read its measured values on a computer. When the device is connected with USB, its display lights up and shows the status of the connected to computer. The USB port of this device follows the HID type protocol.

I've successfully connected this device to a Raspberry Pi Zero W and can retrieve data(I connected device to pi board with otg cable). However, I'm seeking a method to automate the USB connection and disconnection process. I can bind and unbind the device using commands, but after rebinding, The screen does not show the status of the computer and it is not possible to receive the measured values from it.

Is there an additional steps required to successfully disconnect and reconnect this HID device?

information:

```
sudo uhubctl  //when rpi turn on and for first time
Current status for hub 1 [1d6b:0002 Linux 6.1.21+ dwc_otg_hcd DWC OTG Controller 20980000.usb, USB 2.00, 1 ports, ppps]
  Port 1: 0303 power lowspeed enable connect [0c45:7406 SONiX USB Device]
  
sudo uhubctl //after connect and disconnect USB cable manually
No compatible devices detected!
Run with -h to get usage info.

dmesg:
hid-generic 0003:0C45:7406.0001: hiddev96,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [SONiX USB Device]          on usb-20980000.usb-1/input0

raspberrypi:/sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic# ls
0003:0C45:7406.000A  bind  new_id  uevent  unbind

raspberrypi:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid# ls
1-1:1.0  bind  module  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
```

command that I use for bind and unbind:

```
echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind
echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/bind
```

[image]